# Добавить символ в начало и конец строки php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, передаю с помощью `textarea` `post` `php` такой текст:

`Text1
Text2
Text3`

Принимаю текст со строками так - `echo nl2br($_POST['list']);`
Вопрос, как в начало и конец каждой строки добавить символы, что бы текст получился таким:

`(Text1)
(Text2)
(Text3)`

Comment: _что бы текст получился таким_
Каким таким? в скобках и каждое слово на одной строке? Второй вопрос, где вы проверяете результат, в браузере?

Answer (score 0):

> *как в начало и конец каждой строки добавить символы?*

```
if ( ($list = nl2br($_POST['list'])) ) {
    $list = preg_replace('~^(?:[\w\h\pP](?!$)?)+~m', '($0)', $list);
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <p><b>Введите ваш отзыв:</b></p>
    <p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="list"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
<?=$list?>
```